# Undefined index: submission with html5

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

When I hit submit on my on page the info does go into the database but I keep on getting undefined for some  and im not getting the bounce data from sample in the javascript.

**Notice**:  Undefined index: sample in

```
<div id="have"><  id="<?php echo 'sample' ?>" onChange="calcnum()"width="500" 
     height="500" style="border:1pt solid black"></div>
      <input type="hidden" name="number" id="number" />
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="form">
<input name="save" type="hidden"  value="<? echo $_POST['sample']?>" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" onChange="calcnum()" value="submit" />
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="savelayout" />
    </form>
```

And java -

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

  function calc()
   {

     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
    else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    val1 = document.getElementById("sample").value;


    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
               {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{

  document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  document.getElementById("sample").value = xmlhttp.responseText;

}}
   }
 </script>
```

Any pointers would greatly be appreciated thanks :)

Comment: What's going on here: "<div id="have"><  id="<?php echo 'sample' ?>" onChange="calcnum()"width="500" 
     height="500" style="border:1pt solid black"></div>"

Comment: Yeah I was just about to ask the same thing. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with your code?

Comment: also this code is calling `calcnum()` and not `calc()`

Comment: how it works is someone marks or circles a image and then it saves it in the database.. but it saves it as text... I know how to bring up the text.. I am just having a hard time bouncing the text.. which it shows fine on sample.. As for the  id="<?php echo 'sample' ?>"  I tried to use id="sample" and that part didn't work either.. Thanks for the calnum to i missed that

Comment: Really? That doesn't answer my question at all and doesn't even come close to what I am asking about.. why would you close it? How do you reopen this? Why is it with stackoverflow the last 4 questions I have asked have gotten minus's and they where never really answered.. ????

Answer (score 1):

To fix the undefined error change this:

```
<? echo $_POST['sample']?>
```

to this:

```
<? if (isset($_POST['sample'])) {echo $_POST['sample'];} ?>
```

Comment: Thankyou... but then all I got was null.. Didn't work